# python-django template-inheritance not working when referencing multiple blocks in base

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am fairly new to django and am trying out template-inheritance but not able to get it work. I cannot get all the blocks in a page to be displayed simultaneously. Not sure if I am missing something in urls, views or settings. I am using Python 3.6 in venv / Django 2.0.4 on PyCharm

Details of my example below - myhome being project name and smarthome being app name

**Folder Structure**

[image]

**base.html**

[image]

**navtopbar.html**

[image]

**navsidebar.html**

[image]

**smarthome urls.py**

[image]

**smarthome views.py**

[image]

-- Initially I had this as base.html but based on advice in thread below, changed to navtopbar. But then not sure how to get application to display navsidebar simultaneously

**settings**
[image]

I followed the advice in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688569/django-template-extends-not-working?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but not able to get it to work yet. Appreciate any help here.

Comment: better write code here then image!

Answer (score 1):

First of all careful with naming!
You are rendering your view in `navtopbar.html`

In `navtopbar.html` you have only override `navtopbar` block so only that block will replaced.

Djnago template works as below:

**base.html**

```
{% block body %} base {% endblock %}
{% block content %} base {% endblock %}
```

Now if you render `home.html` from view it should be:

**home.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<!-- the blocks you override here only replaced -->
{% block body %}
home
{% endblock %}
```

As above html you have only overridden one block which results to override one block and other remains unchanged. the if you want to override `{% block content %}` you need to override in same html as below:

**home.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<!-- the blocks you override here only replaced -->
{% block body %}
home
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
home content
{% endblock %}
```

If you want to include content from another html you can include it with `include` tag

consider below file:

**content.html**

```
<h3>This is common content</h3>
```

now you can include this in your `home.html` as below:

**home.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<!-- the blocks you override here only replaced -->
{% block body %}
home
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% include 'content.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```