# Django Template Extends: Children not overriding parent

Tags: django, templates

I run the `python manage.py runserver` and it displays only the parent - which is **base.html**. According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance), it should override the parent template with the child template:

> Template inheritance allows you to build a base “skeleton” template that contains all the common elements of your site and defines blocks that child templates can override.

**base.html** and **base_child.html** are in the same folder: MyProject/MyApp/Templates/

**views.py**

```
def baseview(request):
    return render(request,'base.html')
```

Here are my templates:

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>
        {% block titleblock %}
        Hello World Title
        {% endblock %}
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        {% block bodyblock %}
        Hello World!
        {% endblock %}
    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

**base_child.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block titleblock %}
Hello Grass title
{% endblock %}

{% block bodyblock %}
Hello Grass!
{% endblock %}
```

I believe the answers and comments for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688569/django-template-extends-not-working) are unclear in description, which is why I pose this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are rendering the base template into your view function.

```
def baseview(request):
   return render(request,'base.html')
```

When you render the base_child template then it override the parent template.

```
def baseview(request):
    return render(request,'child_base.html')
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. In short I guess it can only override if I select it. My problem when I was troubleshooting is that when I should've deleted a field in base_child and then tried your answer. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Both of the templates should be rendered with a different view and url like this:

urls.py for base:

```
url(r'base/$', views.baseview),
```

views.py for base:

```
def baseview(request):
   return render(request,'base.html')
```

urls.py for child:

```
url(r'child/$', views.childview),
```

views.py for child:

```
def childview(request):
   return render(request,'base_child.html')
```

Now when you type

`localhost:8000/base/`

in your browser url it would display base `title`

and if you type

`localhost:8000/child/`

in your browser url it would override the base `title` with child `title`

Comment: You answer is correct according to question. You provided details how to use both templates in different views according to situation. And i nave gave downvote to anyone.@Ahtisham